# How to use Dictionary<string, string> in View(Jquery)?

Tags: c#, jquery, dictionary, model-view-controller, view

I want to display an alert message like follows

```
alert('' + @Model.DictionaryTest["alertInvalidTemplate"] + '');
```

but it does not work, I tried the following way too

```
alert(@Model.DictionaryTest["alertInvalidTemplate"]);
```

and this too

```
alert("" + @Model.DictionaryTest["alertInvalidTemplate"] + "");
```

Comment: the alertInvalidTemplate is your key or value?

Comment: you should write a function like this `$.each(Mydata, function(key, val){
// This function will called for each key-val pair.
// You can do anything here with them.

});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
alert('@Model.DictionaryTest["alertInvalidTemplate"]');
```

Otherwise, you can create hidden, which will hold that value, then get that from JS and show with `alert`.

View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(h => h.DictionaryTest["alertInvalidTemplate"])
```

JS:

```
alert($("#DictionaryTest_alertInvalidTemplate_").val());
```

Notice that in this case, the id of hidden input will become `DictionaryName_Key_` (if you do not specify it manually).